# how to pick some commits to generate patches?

Tags: git, repository, commit, patch

I modify a file in different commits in a repo A, while I keep a another repo B which almost have the same files.

I want to generate some patches from repo A which modify some file and apply them onto repo B.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Answering your main question**: If you want to do this using patches, on repo A:

```
git format-patch <starting hash>..<ending hash>
```

Then, on repo B:

```
git apply <each patch file generated using the above method>
```

I'd caution you to make sure the files are very similar, though. Patches can be a pain to apply correctly if the repositories have diverged much.

**Second approach**: Depending on how similar the repositories are, it may be useful for you to add repo A as a secondary remote for repo B. This would allow you to fetch and cherry-pick commits as you do with any other upstream repository and avoid patch files altogether.

This would look like:

```
git remote add repoA <path to repo A>
git fetch repoA
git cherry-pick <relevant commits in repo A>
```

This:

- Adds Repo A as a second remote.
- Fetches Repo A's commit history.
- Cherry-picks the relevant commits to your current repository.

That said, there is a lot of unnecessary overhead in adding a second remote, such as downloading a lot of unnecessary history, so you may find that patches suit your problem better.